# Network connectivity issue with virtualbox and static ip addressing

Tags: openstack, virtualbox-networking, netplan

I wanted to install and configure openstack to learn it, so i installed two ubuntu servers as virtualbox virtual machines (on my arch linux host) and then i did the configuration based on the documentations from openstack at here: https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/environment-networking-controller.html

So here is my 99_config.yaml file:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp0s3:
            addresses:
                - 10.0.0.11/24
            gateway4: 10.0.0.1
            nameservers:
                search: [controller, compute]
                addresses: [10.0.0.11, 10.0.0.31]
```

Also i set the virtualbox settings as follows: `Bridged Adapter` connected to my laptop's wireless card `wlp59s0` and `Allow All` as the Promiscuous mode. All the other settings are default.

Whenever i apply the config i can't `ping` and i even tried using `netcat` to check the connectivity between my host and the virtual machines but there is no luck. However when i rename the config file and apply netplan again (which is an undo basically), there is no problem pinging.

I would really appreciate any help, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently i was trying to connect my virtual machine whilst my own network was on `192.168.1.x`. As i learned from network principles the first three sets are the network address (and we realize that by checking the netmask (read more about it on network theory books)), so the virtual machine and my own machine must be on the same network. So how i fixed was to set the default gateway to `192.168.1.1` and the virtual machine nodes as `192.168.1.101` and so on. I

hope a newbie like myself finds this helpful :)